# Django ModelChoiceField show specific field and not the pk field

Tags: django, django-models

I'm using django 1.4.5 and I need to show a field in user profile which called 'uuid'

and it is not the pk.

I heard about to_field_name of ModelChoiceField  but apparently this does not work due to
internal bug in django's core.

does anyone manage to show field that is not the pk field?

I was trying to use this patch: https://gist.github.com/drdaeman/5326761

but no avail.

10x

Comment: Why would you want to use a ModelChoiceField? You could view your uuid in a template like {{ user.profile.uuid }} depending on how you configured your user profiles...

Comment: this is a field that lists all users.
The admin should pick one user based on the uuid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField):

> The **unicode** method of the model will be called to generate string
>   representations of the objects for use in the field’s choices; to
>   provide customized representations, subclass ModelChoiceField and
>   override label_from_instance. This method will receive a model object,
>   and should return a string suitable for representing it. For example:

So two options:

```
# in your model
def __unicode__(self):
    return unicode(self.uuid)
```

or, much better if you need to keep a different string representation:

```
from django import forms

class UUIDChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return unicode(obj.uuid)

class FormWithUUIDChoiceField(forms.form):
    field1 = UUIDChoiceField(queryset=..., ...)
```